# c#: transparent in tabControl

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, transparent-control

I'm looking for a way to cause a tabControl (framework 2.0) to be transparent in back ground. 
I have a custom tabControl that inherite from microsoft tabControl. when I'm trying to paint a transparent image in OnPaintBackground the background becomes black. the problem is that I have under the tabContol a panel with background image so I can't paint in the method OnPaintBackground only the color. I'm looking for a way to find the image which located exacly under the tabControl so I'll be able to paint with graphics.drawimage and it will look transparent.

Does someone has an idea with code?
(or another way to do it)

Note: this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true) - does not help!

Answer (score 0):

Mick Doherty claims he has an [transparent tabcontrol](http://dotnetrix.co.uk/controls.htm) control (look for Tabcontrol 2)

Comment: there are no such properties... where did you find those ?

Comment: Didn't really pay attention to what I was finding :) It was code for some custom control...